# Populating Cells with VBA

Tags: vba, excel

There is something going wrong below but I can't work out what. Everything populates except the last two If statements. I am not getting any errors from excel, it just doesn't populate.

```
If NTC.Region.Value = "China" Then
Sheet1.Cells(87, 6).Value = "N/A"
Sheet1.Cells(88, 6).Value = "N/A"

If NTC.RAR.Value = "No" Then
Sheet1.Cells(94, 6).Value = "N/A"

If NTC.Rate1.Value = "Floating" Then
Sheet1.Cells(75, 6).Value = "N/A"

End If
```

Comment: please check online for correct format of `if/then/else` statement in VBA.  also check the format of one-liner `if` statement in VBA

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the lack of `End If` everything is chained to whether or not `NTC.Region.Value = "China"`

Try This:

```
'create a block if because you want to do more than 1 thing
If NTC.Region.Value = "China" Then
    Sheet1.Cells(87, 6).Value = "N/A"
    Sheet1.Cells(88, 6).Value = "N/A"
End if

'Changed to 1 line if statement
If NTC.RAR.Value = "No" Then Sheet1.Cells(94, 6).Value = "N/A"

'Changed to 1 line if statement
If NTC.Rate1.Value = "Floating" Then Sheet1.Cells(75, 6).Value = "N/A"
```